# How to output new line for br in double quote

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```
<script>
var str = "first line <br /> second line <br /> third line";
$(".div_class").prepend(str);
</script>
```

This code do not add break like below

```
first line
second line
third line
```

Rather it shows like `first line <br /> second line <br /> third line`

but I want like the first one so that br tags work. How can I do this?

I am working on ruby on rails

Comment: Looks like a Javascript question, not a Ruby question.

Comment: This seems pure JavaScript, but when I open my console on this page and type `$('#question').prepend("hello<br/>")` it does prepend "hello " with a newline in front of the question div on this page. Seems to work fine.

Comment: Agree with others, this works fine as is. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4q8f2/

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting to text in an HTML context (such as `nodeValue` or `innerText`, you will have to use `\n` and ensure that the container has the CSS `white-space` property set to something that doesn't condence whitespace, such as `pre-wrap`.

Answer (score -1):

Use \r\n instead of br tags. I'd post the code for you but I'm on my phone and I can't use the shortcut keys to do so.